# NSPointerArray access pointer fails

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have this code in a cocoa library:

```
-(NSPointerArray *)  GetRequestsFromCalendar:(int) calid
{
    NSPointerArray * reqs=[[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory];

    for(int i=0;i<5; ++i){
        Request * newreq=new Request();
        [reqs addPointer:newreq];
    }

    for (NSUInteger i=0;i<5;++i) {
        void * ptr=[reqs pointerAtIndex:i];
        std::cout<<*((Request *) ptr)<<std::endl;
    }
```

here I have expected values printed
"Request1"
"Request1"
"Request1"
"Request1"
"Request1"

```
    return reqs;
}
```

When i call this function from other cocoa library, and access the NSPointerArray,

```
NSPointerArray * array=[obj GetRequestsFromCalendar:1]
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<[array count]; ++i) {
    void * ptr=[array pointerAtIndex:i];
    std::cout<<*((Request *) ptr)<<std::endl;
}
```

prints not expected values like 
????aod?)@"?? ....

Request is a c++ class with overloaded the std::ostream & operator <<  And private members std::string name which is initialized to "Request1"

Both libraries use Automatic Reference Counting

The pointers seem to be free after calling the function but I am not sure.
Can anybody help?

Comment: How do you set `ptr` in the c++ example? There's no code like `void * ptr = [array pointerAtIndex:foo];`

Comment: @Chris It's mix objective c and c++ code

Comment: could you post more code please? You  set `array` and then dereference `ptr`. Where is `ptr` set?

Comment: Oups , sorry I forgot to iterate the NSPointerArray , I just edited the code.

Comment: Define "not expected values".

Comment: The expected result is print "Request1" five times. however I see random characters (most of them are '?' )